# Is it Possible to Use Windows Phone 6 SDK with VS 2010 or VS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

I need to convert my old Windows Phone 6 application from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio 2012. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the forums I came to know that Windows Phone 6 SDK is no longer supported in versions 2010 and above

[windows mobile 6 standard sdk not detecting visual studio 2010 beta installed](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vssetup/thread/f2a5feba-2424-4dc7-95c6-a411f24498cd)

[Visual Studio 2010 Lacks Support for WM 6.x App Development](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Visual-Studio-2010-Lacks-Support-for-WM-6-x-App-Development-139781.shtml)

Comment: Seems to be possible with Windows Embedded. http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/windows-embedded.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No, you must used visual studio 2008.
You can see this url (in spanish)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/vstudio/sa69he4t(v=vs.100).aspx